# ListItem in Selectbox preselected (selected)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, qooxdoo

In Qooxdoo based application I have the following problem.
In a for loop I have to add in a Selectbox a ListItem.

```
this._selection.add(new qx.ui.form.ListItem(fieldName, null, field));
this._selection is class type of: **qx.ui.form.SelectBox**
```

I want a particular ListItem I added in this Selectbox pre-selected.
In HTML it is:

```
<option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
```

best, Tamer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setSelection` method to do that. Here's an example, as derived from the demobrowser SelectBox demo at http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#widget~SelectBox.html:

```
var selectBox = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
for (var i=0; i<30; i++)
{
  var tempItem = new qx.ui.form.ListItem("Item " + (i+1));
  selectBox.add(tempItem);

  // select sixth item
  if (i == 5)
  {
    selectBox.setSelection([tempItem]);
  }
}
```

Derrell

Comment: Dear Derell, 
Thank you very much. 

It seems to work